# Prevent installing android app with specific package name

Tags: android, installation, package, uninstallation

I am developing two android apps with android studio and for some reason I want just one of these apps can be installed on a device. I think I should check the package name of second app and prevent it from installing. Is there any way to do that? thanks.

Comment: Give the same application id for both of you'r app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not prevent any app from being installation. Instead you can stop your app from being running. I mean, when your app starts, check if specific application is installed, and if so stop your application.

Answer (score 1):

An ordinary app cannot prevent another app from being installed. Malware authors would think that such a "feature" would be wonderful.

Device owner apps — mostly for IT departments at larger organizations — have some abilities here, though I forget whether they can block installation by package name.

Comment: Do you have any ordinary suggestion for this problem?

Comment: @SinaKhorshidian: Since you cannot prevent the user from installing both apps, find a way for both apps to co-exist.