# Block specific app install by package name

Tags: android, apk

I want block install one or two application to install.
For example: i want application which has "com.aaa.aaa" package name. How can i do it? And i want do this without robot access.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: You can't. AFIK

Comment: You want to stop them from installing it?  You'd need to be set as the device owner and use the enterprise functionality to do so.  Which would basically only be viable if you physically set up the devices yourself, not for a Play Store app.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51223147/3501524